# how to recognize when to use : or = in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

How can I recognize when to use `:` or `=` in my code? I came from Java which does not have many `:` in it, so it's a new thing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we want to define property of an object then we always use `:`

*Syntax*

```
var object = {
property1 : value1,
property2 : value2,
property2 : value3
}
```

We always separate properties with comma in a single object

`=` Equal to always use as a assignment operator which assigns values to variables or constants

*Syntax*

```js
var variable=value
```

value can be any type You can see this document for that

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

Answer (score 3):

`=` is used to assign a value to a variable:

```
myVariable = 'someValue';
```

`:` is used when defining a property of an object:

```
myVariable = {
    key: 'value in an object'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use the `:` in objects for example:

`object { car: 'BMW' }`

And the `=` you use to define or update variables, example:

`const car = 'BMW'; car = 'Mercedes-Benz'`

Answer (score 0):

```
: vs =
```

: is used in object, That is while assigning value's to key ex:-

```
 const newObject = { key:value }
```

but when you assign some value to variable `=` sign is used